# XLST Formating of XML tag issue

Tags: xml, xslt

Am new to XSLT , need the XSLT code to transform the below XML input to XML output.

Input:

```
<Raj>
   <A>1</A>
   <B>3</B>
   <D></D>
   <E></E>
</Raj>
```

Output:

```
<Raj>
   <Request>
       <A>1</A>
       <B>3</B>
       <D></D>
       <E></E>
   </Request>
</Raj>
```

Comment: You've got to try something. Post your XSLT and you will get help fixing it.

Comment: you can use <xsl:copy-of> or <xsl:copy> depending on how you code your xslt

Answer (score 0):

For XSL 1.0, Try something like this

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(current())}">
      <Request>
        <xsl:copy-of select="child::*"/>
      </Request>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```